# Add referenced name instead of ID from comobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 tables. First has column (categoryID) that is foreign key for categoryID in second table.Second table has 2 columns (categoryID, categoryName). After bit struggling I've displayed in combobox categoryName instead of categoryID. But now when I want to choose from existing categoryName that is already created (displayed in dropdown in combobox), is not possible because I have to type there int not string format. I'm beginner in programming

```
con.Open();
        string cmddt = "insert into wallettbl(sum, date, categoryID, type)   
        values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + 
        comboBox1.Text + "', '" + type + "')";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmddt, con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How to write code if I want to add string (from combobox) instead of int, but in first table will be added categoryID which is referenced to categoryName.
EDIT: added code for combobox

```
 con.Open();
                string cmddt = "select categoryNAME from categoryTbl";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmddt, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmddt, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Comment: It never cease to amaze me that in 2019 people are still writing code that's vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameterized quries!

Comment: Please use [parameters](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/). As to your question, items in the combobox are objects and whatever is returned by ToString() is the displayed value. You could create your own class that has the CatagoryID and CategoryName (returned by ToString()) and use the CatagoryID property as a query parameter.

Comment: What type of application is this? A Combobox is slightly different between WinForms, WPF, MS Access, and ASP.NET. So please tag one of those (or whatever it is you're using). Also, it would help if you posted the code you are using to populate your combo box.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @JohnWu, I was speaking to WinForms in my earlier comment.

Comment: @ZoharPeled like I said Im beginner in programing. I will look on parameterized quries. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DávidDopirák The fact that most beginners make such mistakes is telling me we have terrible tutorials or worst, terrible teachers in the industry. I'm not blaming the beginners, of course, but those who teach them should definitely know better.

Answer (score 0):

change the query to load the categories as below:

```
string cmddt = "select categoryID, categoryNAME from categoryTbl";
```

Set the datasource for comboBox1 as below:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "categoryNAME";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "categoryID";
```

and finally modify the code to insert data into the wallettbl as follows:

```
string cmddt=
            @"INSERT INTO WALLETTBL(sum, date, categoryID, type)   
    VALUES (@Sum, @Date, @CategoryId, @Type);";

         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
         {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn))
            {
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = textBox2.Text;
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryId", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = type;
               await conn.OpenAsync();
               await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
         }
```

Comment: _System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__wallettbl__categ__75A278F5"._

Comment: Debug and find out the value of categoryId that is getting inserted. it should be present in the category table